# Time to the next alarm in seconds or milliseconds

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

With this code I am able to take some string like "Wed 10:10",

```
String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```

but I want to have a value of seconds to the next alarm. Is that possible ?
Also it would be nice for me if I am able to read the value of the description field, and the days when this alarm is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it by following way

```
private void updateAlarmDate(String nextAlarm) {
    if (nextAlarm.length()==0 || nextAlarm == "") {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE hh:mm aa");
        Date alarmDate = null;
        try {
            alarmDate = sdf.parse(nextAlarm);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int alarmDay = alarmDate.getDay();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date currentDate = now.getTime();
        int todayDay = currentDate.getDay();
        int daysDiff = 0;
        if (todayDay > alarmDay) {
            daysDiff = ((7 + (alarmDay - todayDay)) % 7) + 1;
        } else {
            daysDiff = ((7 + (alarmDay - todayDay)) % 7);
        }
        now.add(Calendar.DATE, daysDiff);
        AlarmFulldate = now.getTime();
        AlarmFulldate.setHours(alarmDate.getHours());
        AlarmFulldate.setMinutes(alarmDate.getMinutes());
        AlarmFulldate.setSeconds(0);
    }
}
```

long millis = AlarmFulldate.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
Variable millis will have milliseconds.

Use following code to get days, hours and min from millis

```
days = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
hours = (int) ((millis - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
min = (int) (millis - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * hours))/(1000 * 60);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: AlarmFulldate just needs to be replaced with "Date"